# Fatal error: Call to undefined function _ds_inception_get_overrides()

Tags: 7

I am trying to run the cron job in a drupal website that my client gave me then I tried to update the cron job for search and after the cron jobs finished then my drupal installation turn into this error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function `_ds_inception_get_overrides()` in C:\Apache24\htdocs\sites\uqsport.com.au\modules\ds_inception\includes\ds_inception.pages.inc on line 37

I have searched everywhere in google but it seems other people don't have this kind of problem before so it kind of make me perplexed as to how this error came upon me? 
I just need to know how the above error happened? and what is the solution.
any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks though.

**update**.

this is what ds_inception.info contains.

```
 name = Display Suite Inception
description = Create flexible layout pages (Drupal within Drupal) on top of Display Suite.
package = "Display Suite"
core = 7.x
files[] = ds_inception.class.inc
files[] = ds_inception.module
dependencies[] = "ds_inception_fields"
dependencies[] = "ds"
dependencies[] = "ds_extras"
dependencies[] = "views"
dependencies[] = "ctools"
dependencies[] = "entity"
dependencies[] = "list"
configure = admin/config/user-interface/inception


; Information added by cms-build component-build on October 24 2016
version = "7.x-1.0"
core = "7.x"
project = "ds_inception"
datestamp = "201610241316"
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! We cannot help you without seeing the code you are using. It's not even clear how you are manipulating the search index, from the  question, nor where `_ds_inception_get_overrides()` would be defined.

Comment: well actually I just try to run the cron job because it hadn't been run in 2 month based on the message that cron gave me. and after I ran the cron job then that error shows up. so I am not exactly sure what I did wrong except running the cron. can you tell me what cron job do exactly when it ran in drupal? does it change anything?

Comment: What's is file have function **_ds_inception_get_overrides()** write in file? You need use [module_load_include](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_load_include/7.x) and load it in file ds_inception.pages.inc.

Comment: how to load it? you mean I should add the function in ds_inception.pages.inc?

Comment: What's file have function _ds_inception_get_overrides()?

Comment: how to find such file?

Comment: :( Just use ide (netbean, sublimetext, phpstorm) and find text in root folder of project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Drupal runs its cron tasks, it runs also every implementation of `hook_cron()` made from every module, including the core ones. Those implementation can then invoke other hooks, even the ones implemented by modules not implementing `hook_cron()`.

The error you are showing is caused from the module whose machine name is ds_inception. Whenever it is implementing `hook_cron()` or one of the hooks invoked from `hook_cron()`, you need to disable that module.

I cannot tell you the name of the module you read in the page listing all the enabled modules, since I didn't find any third-party module with that machine name hosted on drupal.org. I thought it was a sub-module of the [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) module, but the [7.x-1.x branch](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/ds/tree/modules?h=7.x-1.x) doesn't contain such module, nor does the [7.x-2.x branch](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/ds/tree/modules?h=7.x-1.x). It could also be a custom module developer for that site.
You can still find the readable name of the module in the ds_inception.info file, if you find one. It's the one following *name =* in that file.

Comment: so how to disable the module ds_inception in drupal?

Comment: There is a page listing all the enabled modules.